# Piping GUNZIP to GREP

Tags: linux, shell, grep, pipe, gunzip

I'm trying to find all ZIP files in a specific folder, extract them using GUNZIP, and pipe the output to GREP to search within HTML files contained in these ZIP files.

I managed to do so with UNZIP (unzip -p), but unfortunately due to many servers that I will eventually run that search on with SSH loop, that doesn't have ZIP/UNZIP installed, I'm limited to GUNZIP which is installed on these old Linux kernel servers, I guess that by default.

Is there a way to pipe the output of gunzip extraction (of more than 1 file following a find -exec command) to grep, in a way that will allow searching inside these HTML files (not in their file names, but within)?

That's how I've tried to do it so far, without succeess:

```
find /home/osboxes/project/ZIPs/*.zip -exec gunzip -l {} \;|grep 'pattern'
```

**UNZIP** has a -p option that can pipe the output and I get the needed result with it, but it seems that **GUNZIP** doesn't...

Can you think of a way to help me make it work?

Appreciated

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/418771/uncompress-and-pipe-the-output-to-script

Comment: @Tds18 : You use the `-l` option of gunzip, which does not output the content of the file. See `man gunzip`.

Comment: [`zgrep`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zgrep) is your friend.

Comment: Though why are you trying to use gzip with zip files? I can't imagine that working well.

Comment: Thanks @Labradorcode, right as well.

Comment: Thanks @user194428, I missed it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`gunzip -c` writes the output to standard output. The original file is not affected. `zcat` also works, it is the same as `gunzip -c`.

Comment: There's also `zgrep`.

Comment: Thank you buddy :) made the difference.